# Unexpected result with sqrt() using pipe in R

Tags: r

The calculation is to square each elements, sum each column, divide by 5, then make the square root. Below is an example:

```
library(magrittr)

a <- matrix(data = c(1,2,100,200), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

The data `a` is:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1  100
[2,]    2  200
```

I tried two ways: the first one used the pipe.

```
(a^2 %>% colSums())/5 %>% sqrt()  # Way 1

sqrt((a^2 %>% colSums())/5)       # Way 2
```

Strangely, `Way 1` and `Way 2` produced different results.

The result of `Way 1` is:

```
[1]     2.236068 22360.679775
```

The result of `Way 2` is:

```
[1]   1 100
```

I expected the result of `Way 2`. How did `Way 1` happen? Why these different results occured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In way1, that result is `(a^2 %>% colSums())/(5 %>% sqrt())`

If you want way2's result in way1, you should use `((a^2 %>% colSums())/5) %>% sqrt()`

Answer (score 1):

As @Park already pointed out, this is about operator precedence. I would advise a different solution, though. You are mixing pipes and conventional function calling and that is the underlying cause for your problem.

If you change the division to be another step in the pipe, everything is correct and consistent. You could do it like this

```
a^2 %>% colSums() %>% `/`(5) %>% sqrt()
```

That spares brackets, gives computation a natural order (reading from left to right) and the result is correct:

```
> a^2 %>% colSums() %>% `/`(5) %>% sqrt() 
[1]   1 100
```

If you wanted to be totally consistent you could even make that

```
a %>% 
   `^`(2) %>% 
        colSums() %>% 
            `/`(5) %>% 
                 sqrt()
```